# What is the purpose of the recursive definition of x[[c(1,3)]]?

Tags: r, subset

`x[c(1, 3)]` returns the first and third elements of `x`, and `x[[c(1, 3)]]` returns the third element of the first element of x. This seems incongruent to me. The two seem to have completely different methods of thinking. Why are they labelled similarly?

The second way of writing it, `x[[1]][[3]]` seems more intuitive to me.

Comment: x is a list with at least 3 elements

Comment: I feel like I know the difference between [ and [[, but I am confused about the fact that c(1, 3) targets two elements at once in [, but seems to target one over the other in [[.

Comment: `x[[1]][3]` is the way I would write it. "The third element of the first list element of x."

Comment: I'm not sure what to say except that it's documented: "[[ can be applied recursively to lists, so that if the single index i is a vector of length p, alist[[i]] is equivalent to alist[[i1]]...[[ip]] providing all but the final indexing results in a list."

Comment: This does seem like really odd behavior to me, that a vector inside `[[` would be applied recursively.

Comment: @SeñorO but as joran says.... *it's documented behaviour*.. I'm sure there is a Ripleyism about documented behaviour vs. user expectations.

Comment: Ah okay Joran so it's just defined like that. That eases me a little bit but I am still uneasy about the incongruity. I don't get why they don't just stick to the x[[1]][3] version, considering c(1,3) has a different meaning in [[.

Comment: @SimonO'Hanlon well said.

Comment: @user1614466 I think you have a point, but who do you complain to when you're using open source software?

Comment: Since we're guessing, here's my guess: `x[[c(1,3)]]` is meant to mimic *matrix* indexing. That is, `x[1,3]` selects the third element of the first row of a matrix, while `x[[c(1,3)]]` selects the third element of the first element of a list ... if you had deeply nested lists it might feel simpler to index `x[[c(a,b,c,d)]]` rather than `x[[a]][[b]][[c]][[d]]`

Comment: It makes sense to me, once you start from the premise that `[` is for selecting sub-lists and `[[` is for selecting _single elements_. In that context, `x[[c(1,3)]]` still needs to return a single value, and the recursive definition seems like a reasonable way to go. Probably someone along the way just thought it would be a useful idiom.

Comment: It's definitely a reasonable way to go if you want to use c(1,3) in the first place, but I feel it would make more sense to only denote it with x[[1]][3] since c(1,3) has a different meaning in [[, since c(1,3) contains two "simultaneous" values. Splitting them up and making one take priority over the other feels less intuitive to me than x[[1]][3].

Comment: @BenBolker I think you're right. That makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `x[[c(1,3)]]` is equivalent to `x[[1]][[3]]` when you are typing numbers by hand, but what about in this case:

```
a <- c(1,3)
x[[a]]
```

Sure you can write that as

```
a <- c(1,3)
x[[ a[1] ]][[ a[2] ]]
```

but that only works if you know that `a` will have exactly 2 elements.  What if you are constructing a as part of a function while creating and or parsing the list `x`?  Without the option of `x[[a]]` you would need to write a recursive function that accessed the `a[1]`th element of `x` then called itself with the 1st value of `a` popped off and the result of subsetting `x`.  The `x[[a]]` syntax is simpler (and possibly safer).